# Join таблиц и последнее актуальное значение

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 10.
Есть 2 таблицы

items:

```
     id(int)|name(varchar)
     ----------------------
       1    |   aaa
       2    |   bbb
       3    |   ccc
       4    |   ddd
       5    |   eee
```

events:

```
  itemid(int) |  value(float)  |     time(int)
  ---------------------------------------------------
          2   |       0         | 132163010988353644 
          3   |       1         | 132163010889858813
          3   |       0         | 132163010568000000
          1   |       1         | 132163010567900000
          2   |       1         | 132163010356945803
          1   |       0         | 132163009306305369
          5   |       1         | 132163009116649666
          4   |       0         | 132163009116630133
          5   |       0         | 132163007565130000


time в формате filetime тип поля int
```

Нужно объединить 2 таблицы, из первой таблицы `items` взять `name`  (LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON items.id = itemid) а из таблицы `events` взять `value` и `time`.
На выходе должно получиться список имён из первой таблицы (каждое имя 1 раз т.е. c помощью DISTINCT) `value` (последнее значение) и `time` (время записи последнего значения `value`)

```
name   |   value   |     time
----------------------------------------
aaa    |    1      |  132163010567900000
bbb    |    0      |  132163010988353644
ccc    |    1      |  132163010889858813
ddd    |    0      |  132163009116630133
eee    |    1      |  132163009116649666
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       items.name,
       FIRST_VALUE(events.value) OVER (PARTITION BY events.itemid ORDER BY events.time DESC),
       MAX(events.time) OVER (PARTITION BY events.itemid)
FROM items
LEFT JOIN events ON items.id = events.itemid
```